# what are x.ngfactory.ts files and how to debug these while I'm using @angular/cli 1.1.1

Tags: angular, webpack-2, typescript2.0

I am using angular 4.x, webpack 2.x, typescript 2.x.

I'm building my project using @angular/cli.

But when I'm doing `ng serve` it works fine all code are getting transpiled succesfully and running in view perfectly fine.

its log is as below:

```
webpack: Compiling...
Hash: 24b7c2a082104ba0df53                                                         
Time: 9187ms
chunk    {0} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 661 kB {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {1} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 160 kB {4} [initial]
chunk    {2} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 285 kB {4} [initial]
chunk    {3} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 5.69 MB [initial]
chunk    {4} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 0 bytes [entry]
webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

But when I'm doing `ng build --prod` it throws several errors as follows:

```
ERROR in F:/$$$A4p/chatbox/clientV2/src/$$_gendir/app/component/profile/view/people/people.component.ngfactory.ts (1292,11): Type 'MProfile | IConversationProfile' is not assignable to
type 'boolean'.
  Type 'MProfile' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

ERROR in F:/$$$A4p/chatbox/clientV2/src/$$_gendir/app/component/profile/view/conversation/conv.component.ngfactory.ts (950,11): Type 'MProfile | IConversationProfile' is not assignable
to type 'boolean'.
  Type 'MProfile' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

ERROR in F:/$$$A4p/chatbox/clientV2/src/$$_gendir/local_node_modules/ngx-uploader/src/module/ngx-uploader.module.ngfactory.ts (10,26): Cannot find module './ngx-uploader.module'.

ERROR in F:/$$$A4p/chatbox/clientV2/src/$$_gendir/app/component/profile/view/people/people.component.ngfactory.ts (1292,11): Type 'MProfile | IConversationProfile' is not assignable to
type 'boolean'.
  Type 'MProfile' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

ERROR in F:/$$$A4p/chatbox/clientV2/src/$$_gendir/app/component/profile/view/conversation/conv.component.ngfactory.ts (950,11): Type 'MProfile | IConversationProfile' is not assignable
to type 'boolean'.
  Type 'MProfile' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

***But when I'm searching for any `...ngfactory.ts` it is not present in file system.***

> So I don't know how to debug these error.

Comment: Withouth having the source code is hard to tell what is going on. Its AOT related though, but I cant say what triggers the errors withouth source

Answer (score 1):

NgFactory files are the real files while your page runs. At development stage you have template file and .ts file. When you compile your project by using 
`ng build --prod` it runs AOT too and AOT merges these two files into ngFactories priorly. JIT also doing the similar thing though, but on run time.

You do not get same error without AOT because JIT ignores those template errors.

Check out your template files, you have type casting erros, such like

```
Type 'MProfile' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't really answer to the 2nd part of the question, how to debug them.